# Updating a Laravel model with a unique field

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am unable to update a model, if it has a unique field. I get the message "The name has already been taken."

My controller:

```
/**
 * Update the specified Category in storage.
 *
 * @param  int              $id
 * @param UpdateCategoryRequest $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id, UpdateCategoryRequest $request)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($category)) {
        Flash::error('Category not found');

        return redirect(route('categories.index'));
    }

    $category = $this->categoryRepository->update($request->all(), $id);

    Flash::success('Category updated successfully.');

    return redirect(route('categories.index'));
}
```

UpdateCategoryRequest

```
 /**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return Category::$rules;
}
```

Category Model

```
    /**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
public static $rules = [
    'name' => 'required|unique:categories,name'
];
```

I've tried appending to my rules, the following:

```
$this->id
$id

@include('adminlte-templates::common.errors')
       <div class="box box-primary">
           <div class="box-body">
               <div class="row">
                   {!! Form::model($category, ['route' => ['categories.update', $category->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}

                        @include('categories.fields')

                   {!! Form::close() !!}
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Can you include your route definition?

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this worked for me:

In my UpdateCategoryRequest:

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = Category::$rules;
        if ($this->isMethod('patch'))
        {
            $id = $this->categories;
            $rules['name'] = $rules['name'].',name,'.$id;
        }
        return $rules;
    }
```

Comment: In simple terms, you would have to pass the id as a third parameter to ignore the unique check unless the exact same data is been used by another user.

Answer (score 13):

To exclude the current model from the check, pass the id as the `3rd` column.

```
'name' => 'required|unique:categories,name,'. $this->id
```

Comment: This won't work because using $this when not in object context. But it points to the right direction.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy is right, according to the laravel documentation [https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique) -> **Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID**

Answer (score 1):

In your request, just append to the 'name' rule you get from the model.

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = Category::$rules;
    $rules['name'] .= ','. $this->route('id');
    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause'" Is the result I get when saving with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to tackle this by retrieving your rules from the model statically without any changes, because you'll have to append the model id dynamically to the `unique` rule as the third parameter.

To get the model id, you need access to the request, which you only have in your `FormRequest` class, using `$this->route('id')` in your case. Or, if you are using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding) and you have defined your route path like `my/route/{category}`, then:

```
public function rules()
{
    $category = $this->route('category');

    $rules = Category::$rules;
    $rules['name'] .= ",{$category->id}";

    return $rules;
}
```

Unless of course you go fancy and declare a getter method in your model that will accept the id as parameter and build the rule there.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

You need to exclude current model .Since you demand unique for table it is not excluding your current column or say id.

Do edit your request

```
public function rules()
{
    switch($this->method())
    {
        case 'GET':
        case 'DELETE':
        {
            return [];
        }
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|unique:categories',

            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|unique:categories,name,'.$this->getSegmentFromEnd().',id'

        }
        default:break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Undefined variable: id"

Comment: i think error is from view not from request . Please do explain your error completely

Comment: I've added my view, if that helps?

Comment: Here i have made changes on your request file by switching the case .Please review

Answer (score -1):

```
public function update($id, UpdateCategoryRequest $request)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($category)) {
        Flash::error('Category not found');

        return redirect(route('categories.index'));
    }

    $category = $category->update($request->all());

    Flash::success('Category updated successfully.');

    return redirect(route('categories.index'));
}
```

Comment: ok you need to put condition there.Since you have make separate request for the method it willnot recognize your id. I had made slight changes on request page

Comment: Still get the same validation error "The name has already been taken."

Comment: Did you use same code as shown above i mean switch case.Show me your routes too.